# how to do Dynamic selection With VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

Original Code

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet2!$A$1:$A$12,Sheet2!$C$1:$C$12")
```

In this code i want my range selection to be dynamic, i tried the code below, which gives me $A$1:$A$12

```
Range(Range("a1"), Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Address
```

i tried replacing it in the original code but didn't work,

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(""Sheet2"&"!"& Range(Range("a1"), Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Address,Sheet2!$C$1:$C$12")
```

i even tried declaring a variable then adding that to code but still same error

```
cde = "Sheet2" & "!" & Range(Range("a1"), Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Address
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("cde,Sheet2!$C$1:$C$12")
```

What should b the right code?

Comment: `"Sheet2!$A$1:$A$12,Sheet2!$C$1:$C$12"` can be written as `"Sheet2!" & "$A$1:$A$12" & ",Sheet2!" & "$C$1:$C$12"` or simply `"Sheet2!" & rngA & ",Sheet2!" & rngB`.

Comment: @SiddharthRout i dont want to hard code range to $A1$1:$A$12

Comment: I never asked you to hard code... I showed you how you get the address dynamically and then insert in that string

Comment: Don't forget the magic `Range("a1").CurrentRegion`

Answer (score 0):

### Step By Step

- Adjust the worksheet name (`"Sheet2"`, the name in the tabs) and the chart object name (`"Chart 1"`).
- The following solution 'assumes' that the data and the chart object are on the same worksheet. If not, define another worksheet e.g. `ws1` and use it like this:
  `Set cho = ws1.ChartObjects("Chart 1")`

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub populateChart()
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    ' Define worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' Define range.
    Dim rng As Range
    ' If you want to include data from column 'B' then:
    'Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Resize(, 3)
    ' If not then:
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    Set rng = Union(rng, ws.Range(ws.Range("C1"), ws.Range("C1").End(xlDown)))
    ' Define chart object.
    Dim cho As ChartObject
    Set cho = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    ' Set source data.
    cho.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that the chart contains data from columns A and C though, not just A.

Comment: @BigBen: Thanks. Do you think `.Resize( , 3)` is ok? Or is there another catch?

Comment: No (I don't think column B should be included), but `Union` might work

Comment: @BigBen: I still think resize is the way to go, since e.g. `Range(Columns("A"), Columns("C"))` includes column `"B"` (*From, To*).

Comment: Ummm, I don't think you want `Resize`. `? Range("$A$1:$A$12,$C$1:$C$12").Cells.Count` returns `24`, not `36`... it excludes column B.

Comment: @BigBen no column B is not included , only data from column A and column C

Comment: @BigBen: When it is addresses you are right, when it is `Range` (`Cells`) then I am.

Comment: @BigBen: OP commented that he doesn't want column B.

Comment: And `Union` would not include it but `Resize` would... maybe we're saying the same thing but in different words, but I think we both agree.

Comment: @VBasic2008 "Set cho = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1") "   this line gives me error

Comment: @anuraagshukla: When you select the chart object, on the left of the formula bar you can see its name. Use it instead of `"Chart 1"`.

Comment: Instead of `Set rng = Union(rng, ws.Range(ws.Range("C1"), ws.Range("C1").End(xlDown)))`, a better solution would be `Set rng = Union(rng, rng.Offset(, 2))`

Comment: @VBasic2008 but there is no chart, the code didn't populate a chart

Comment: @anuraagshukla: Instead of `Set cho = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")` use   `Set cho = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered)`

Comment: @VBasic2008 it gives me runtime error"13"  type mismatch

Comment: @VBasic2008 i have noticed if i first add a chart in sheet then use your code  `Set cho = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")` it works fine

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
Private Sub Macro1()
Dim fc As String
Dim sc As String
Dim ra As String

fc = "chart!" & Range(Range("A1"), Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Address
sc = "chart!" & Range(Range("c1"), Range("c1").End(xlDown)).Address
ra = fc & "," & sc

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(ra)
End Sub
```